# Traceback <module> from extractdocx import * <module> from docx import opendocx, getdocumenttext from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, pip

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\xampp\htdocs\Plag\scripts\main.py", line 8, in 
from extractdocx import *
File "C:\xampp\htdocs\Plag\scripts\extractdocx.py", line 18, in 
from docx import opendocx, getdocumenttext
File "C:\Users\zeesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\docx.py", line 30, in 
from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

````
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Master script for the plagiarism-checker
# Coded by: Shashank S Rao

#import other modules
from cosineSim import *
from htmlstrip import *
from extractdocx import *

#import required modules
import codecs
import traceback
import sys
import operator
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import json as simplejson

# Given a text string, remove all non-alphanumeric
# characters (using Unicode definition of alphanumeric).
def getQueries(text,n):
   import re
   sentenceEnders = re.compile('[.!?]')
   sentenceList = sentenceEnders.split(text)
   sentencesplits = []
   for sentence in sentenceList:
       x = re.compile(r'\W+', re.UNICODE).split(sentence)
       x = [ele for ele in x if ele != '']
       sentencesplits.append(x)
   finalq = []
   for sentence in sentencesplits:
       l = len(sentence)
       l=l/n
       index = 0
       for i in range(0,l):
           finalq.append(sentence[index:index+n])
           index = index + n-1
       if index !=len(sentence):
           finalq.append(sentence[len(sentence)-index:len(sentence)])
   return finalq

# Search the web for the plagiarised text
# Calculate the cosineSimilarity of the given query vs matched content on google
# This is returned as 2 dictionaries 
def searchWeb(text,output,c):
   try:
       text = text.encode('utf-8')
   except:
       text =  text
   query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text)
   if len(query)>60:
       return output,c
   #using googleapis for searching web
   base_url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='
   url = base_url + '%22' + query + '%22'
   request = urllib.request.Request(url,None,{'Referer':'Google Chrome'})
   response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
   results = simplejson.load(response)
   try:
       if ( len(results) and 'responseData' in results and 'results' in results['responseData'] and results['responseData']['results'] != []):
           for ele in  results['responseData']['results']:       
               Match = results['responseData']['results'][0]
               content = Match['content']
               if Match['url'] in output:
                   #print text
                   #print strip_tags(content)
                   output[Match['url']] = output[Match['url']] + 1
                   c[Match['url']] = (c[Match['url']]*(output[Match['url']] - 1) + cosineSim(text,strip_tags(content)))/(output[Match['url']])
               else:
                   output[Match['url']] = 1
                   c[Match['url']] = cosineSim(text,strip_tags(content))
   except:
       return output,c
   return output,c
   

# Use the main function to scrutinize a file for
# plagiarism
def main():
   # n-grams N VALUE SET HERE
   n=9
   if len(sys.argv) <3:
       print ("Usage: python main.py <input-filename>.txt <output-filename>.txt")
       sys.exit()
   if sys.argv[1].endswith(".docx"):
       t = docxExtract(sys.argv[1])
   else:
       t=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
       if not t:
           print ("Invalid Filename")
           print ("Usage: python main.py <input-filename>.txt <output-filename>.txt")
           sys.exit()
       t=t.read()
   queries = getQueries(t,n)
   q = [' '.join(d) for d in queries]
   found = []
   #using 2 dictionaries: c and output
   #output is used to store the url as key and number of occurences of that url in different searches as value
   #c is used to store url as key and sum of all the cosine similarities of all matches as value   
   output = {}
   c = {}
   i=1
   count = len(q)
   if count>100:
       count=100
   for s in q[:100]:
       output,c=searchWeb(s,output,c)
       msg = "\r"+str(i)+"/"+str(count)+"completed..."
       sys.stdout.write(msg);
       sys.stdout.flush()
       i=i+1
   #print ("\n")
   f = open(sys.argv[2],"w")
   for ele in sorted(iter(c.items()),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
       f.write(str(ele[0])+" "+str(ele[1]*100.00))
       f.write("\n")
   f.close()
   print ("\nDone!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   try:
       main()
   except:
       #writing the error to stdout for better error detection
       error = traceback.format_exc()
       print(("\nUh Oh!\n"+"Plagiarism-Checker encountered an error!:\n"+error)) ```
````

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

[docx](https://pypi.org/project/docx/), last release was in 2014. [The code](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/4c9b46dbebe3d2a9b82dbcd35af36584a36fd9fe/docx.py#L30) imports module `exceptions` that was a top-level module in Python 2.7 but was removed in Python 3:

```
$ python2.7 -c "import exceptions"
$ python3.7 -c "import exceptions"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

The bottom line: the package is only for Python 2. Use Python 2.7 or find a different package.